# want to send same random number to user's mail that are stored in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a web application in which I have one Inquiry form and in that form I'm generating one random number and storing it in the database. My code looks like

```
 clsInquiry objInquiry = new clsInquiry();
    try
    {   

        cn.Open();

        objInquiry.RandomStr = GetUniqueKey(10);


        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add(txt_eid.Text);

        mail.Body += "Thank u for putting inquiry for " + productName + " ;<br><br>";
        mail.Body += "Please Click on Following Link To Download Your Demo" + "<br><br>";

        mail.Body += "<a href=\"http://www.xyz.co.in/Download.aspx?No='" + GetUniqueKey(10) + "'\">Demo Download</a>";
        //mail.Body += "<a href=\"" + MyUrl + "\">Demo Download</a>";
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com ", "****");
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Send(mail);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
```

and function for random Number.....

```
public static string GetUniqueKey(int maxSize)
{
   //code for it

}
```

and I have successfully generated and stored the number in the database ..

but in the `url` of the `hyperlink` in `mail.body` that I've called random number function to send to user, different random number is generated .. I want the same random number in both places.what should I do ?

Comment: Generate the number and place the value into a variable.  Use only this variable to reference the random number that was generated.  In other words you should reference `objInquiry.RandomStr` instead of generating a new number by calling your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the generated random value in a variable and use that in both places (`objInquiry.RandomStr` and `mail.Body`)

```
var randomstr = GetUniqueKey(10);
objInquiry.RandomStr = randomstr;
        ...
mail.Body += "<a href=\"http://www.xyz.co.in/Download.aspx?No='" + randomstr + "'\">Demo Download</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling the GetUniqueKey(10) method two time. It will always return you different unique key.

Get the output of the GetUniqueKey(10) method in a variable and use that variable in both places.